# No visible @interface for 'xxx' declares the selector 'init:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have an objective-c class which tries to init a Swift class object using:

```
- (id) init : (ObjCTestClass*) testclass
{
    NSLog( @"Creating" );

    self = [super init];
    if ( !self )
    {
        return nil;
    }
    self.testclass = testclass;
    self.swiftClass = [[SwiftClass alloc] init: self.testclass];
    return self;
}
```

Here is the corresponding Swift class:

```
final class SwiftClass: NSObject {

    private var objcTestClass: ObjCTestClass

    init(testclass:ObjCTestClass) {
        provider = CXProvider(configuration: type(of: self).providerConfiguration)
        objcTestClass = testclass
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> No visible @interface for 'xxx' declares the selector 'init:'

**Note:**
ObjCTestClass is an objective-c class. 
I have bridging headers to expose objective-c to Swift and vice-versa.

How to fix this?

Comment: Does it need to be `[[SwiftClass alloc] initWith: self.testclass];` ?

Comment: swift class defines:

init(testclass:ObjCTestClass) {

I am not sure where initWith comes from. I tried and it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I mis-spoke it should be `[[SwiftClass alloc] initWithTestClass: self.testclass]`. This should autocomplete when you're typing if it's setup correctly.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Your suggestion worked. I looked at -Swift.h to understand what has happening. Please post your suggestion as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be [[SwiftClass alloc] initWithTestClass: self.testclass]. This should autocomplete when you're typing if it's setup correctly

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the above problem by setting the property explicitly after init:

```
final class SwiftClass: NSObject {

    **public var objcTestClass: ObjCTestClass!**

    init() {
        provider = CXProvider(configuration: type(of: self).providerConfiguration)
        super.init()
    }
}


- (id) init : (ObjCTestClass*) testclass
{
    NSLog( @"Creating" );

    self = [super init];
    if ( !self )
    {
        return nil;
    }
    self.testclass = testclass;
    **self.swiftClass = [[SwiftClass alloc] init];
    self.swiftClass.objcTestClass = self.testclass;**
    return self;
}
```